# Keeping the overlay text fixed [html]

Tags: html, text, overlay, figure

I have an overlay text that appears when you move the mouse cursor on top of a figure. I would like to keep the overlay fixed. That is, always showing the text without the need of moving the cursor on the figure.

In other words, instead of this...
[image: The way it is right now.]

...I would like to have the text fixed like this:
[image: The way I would like to have it.]

Below is the code I have:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 fh5co-work-wrap">
<a href="http://people.tamu.edu/~nsthiago/Hollenbach_Silva_JOP_2018.pdf" target="_blank" class="fh5co-work-item js-fh5co-work-item">
<img src="images/jop_2018.png" alt="Image"  class="img-responsive">
<div class="fh5co-overlay-bg js-fh5co-overlay-bg"></div>
<div class="fh5co-overlay-text js-fh5co-overlay-text">
<h2> Fiscal Capacity and Inequality: Evidence from Brazilian Municipalities [JOP 2018] </h2>
<ul class="fh5co-categories">
<li>With Florian Hollenbach</li>
</ul>
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

Here is the link to my website with more examples: http://people.tamu.edu/~nsthiago/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text and it's white background are set to `opacity: 0` and then changed on hover with javascript. Just open the CSS files, and change opacity to `1`. Right here:

```
.fh5co-overlay-text,
.fh5co-overlay-bg {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0; // change this to 1
}
```

Line 347 - 351 of style.scss

Comment: is it possible to have opacity:1 for desktop version, but opacity:0 for mobile version?

Comment: Yes. You can set css normally, but then use a media query to say "If the browser is this wide or smaller, use this CSS instead". It looks like this: `@media (max-width: 768px){ .div { color: red; } }` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KL-z9A56SQ